# Test class error: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: DUPLICATE_USERNAME, Duplicate Username

Tags: apex

The username already exists in this or another Salesforce organization. Usernames must be unique across all Salesforce organizations. To resolve, use a different username (it doesn't need to match the user's email address). : [Username]

Getting the above error while trying to run the test class. Kindly provide the solution to fix it in the test class.

I tried to made the changes on the emails address

Answer (score 0):

We cannot use duplicate email address as the error message says.

We can either create a factory method to create and use the same user everytime in all the test methods or create a new user with different username everytime